# Create Dropdown from List<Object>

Tags: json, flutter, dart, httprequest, dropdown

Firstly I have this classes to get json data from api

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class Offices {
  final String name, value;
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  Offices(this.name, this.value);
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @override
  String toString() => '$name [$value]';
}

class DeltaPrima {
  DeltaPrima._();
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static const _url = 'http://deltaprima.rmdoo.com/api/office/all';
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<List<Offices>?> getOffices(String token) async {
    var result =
        (await HttpReqService.get<List>(_url, headers: {'CompanyCode': token}));
    if (result == null) return null;
    var list = result
        .cast<JMap>()
        .map((m) => Offices(m['CODD_DESC']!, m['CODD_VALU']!))
        .toList();
    print('Objects => $list');
    return list;
  }
}
```

Then to run it i have `getCust()` method like this.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getCust() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse("http://deltaprima.rmdoo.com/api/business");
    var response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print("error");
      return null;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        data = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        offices = DeltaPrima.getOffices(data["CODD_VALU"]);
      });
    }
  }
```

and after I run those code I have this return

```
Objects => [DELTA PRIMA [01], SAMPLE [02]]
```

I want those `DELTA PRIMA` and `SAMPLE` to become items in the dropdown widget. Then I want `01` and `02` as their value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create `Dropdown` for **Office** Model like this

```
DropdownButton<Offices>(
      items: offices.map((Offices ofc) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<Offices>(
          value: ofc,
          child: Text(ofc.name),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (_) {},
    )
```

Comment: `ofc.value`  is error and showwing The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offices?'.

Comment: updated sorry my bad.

Comment: no error show on my VSCode but in my app its shoe waring red error.. it say "NoSuchMethofError: Class'Future<list<offices>>' has no instance method 'map'. Reciever: Instance of 'Future<list<offices>>' tried calling: map(Closure:(ffices => DropdownMenuItem<Ofices>))"

Comment: that is unrelated to the question. check your API call and other stuff.